# Ajax beginform() is not working

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, model-view-controller, partial-views

I m trying to load a partial view in particular div using ajax form begin But it was not working at the sametime please help me while click submit button i need to load my partial view into div

Master Page :

```
   <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" >    
<div>
 <div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">PageName</asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
    <div id="content">
       <div id="sidebar">

        <asp:Menu ID="menuBar" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False" runat="server"
                BackColor="Black" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="0.8em"
                ForeColor="White" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px">
                <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid"
                    BorderWidth="1px" />
                <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="10px" VerticalPadding="7px" BorderColor="White"
                    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12px" />                                        
                                    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid"
                    BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="Black" />                    
            </asp:Menu>               
       </div>            
      <div id="main">
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
       </div>
      </div>         
</form>
```

View Page :

```
 <%  using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetTruckExpensesChild", new { id="EX1001" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "List" }))
       {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
    <div> <input type="submit" name="dina" value="show list" </div>
    <div id="List">  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you should have the follow bundle addition.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));
```

And in your HTML, make sure both bundles are called.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

For detail check this link -

[Using AJAX to load a partial view not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864458/using-ajax-to-load-a-partial-view-not-working)

Comment: No where is bundle and may be its java script

Comment: Try by using Html.BeginForm. For detail check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496445/ajax-beginform-helper-not-loading-partial-view-into-specified-div

Comment: Also check you have included -

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>